# 3-column Web Parts Page?

Tags: asp.net, html, css, web-parts, portlet

I am setting up an asp.net web parts portal for some stuff. I have a [hopefully] really easy question. How can I make the page have 3 major columns?

Right now I have two columns using `<div id="leftpanel" style="float: left">` and `<div id="rightpanel" style="float: right">`. But I cannot figure out how to get a panel in the center. The right panel is basically in the center and there is not a css float: middle/center. So how is a three panel web parts page accomplished?

Comment: You don't need to float the right hand column right. I always tend to float elements left (because that is the way Westerners read), unless of course it is a single element on the right hand side of the page (where you could just float left and use a margin)

Comment: That did not work well. Looked different in each browser

Comment: The only browser it would look different in would be IE6 due to the double margin bug, which you could fix with display: inline; on the floated elements. 

If it looked different in any other browser then you are doing it wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="column">
   </div>
   <div class="column">
   </div>
   <div class="column">
   </div> 
</div>
<div class="footer">
</div>

.container{width: 600px;}
.column{float: left; width: 200px;}
.footer{width: 600px; clear: both;}
```

Comment: My monitor is in 1920x1200 resolution right now; I'd be a bit sad about this design

Comment: @theorise - Sure, but it's *constant* for all users as written. You should use `%` to define your widths, so that the layout can change with the users' browser.

Comment: @Kevin Vermeer again, the width is arbitrary. This answered OPs question. This isn't an argument about fluid/fixed layouts.

Answer (score -1):

float the first two left and the last one right.

If that doesn't work, and it sometimes won't, then use Ed B's answer.

Answer (score -4):

A table with 3 columns. Add a div in each column.

Keep the style in the divs..not the table

Comment: I'm not going to down-vote this, even though I'm not for table-centric design. Prepare to get flamed by any CSS fanatics though!

Comment: Tables are for tabular content, not layouts.

Comment: Tables are for whatever I want to use them for.

Comment: Sometimes Tables are the absolute best option. I <3 Tables.
You can add width="33%" to the left and right cells, width="34%" to the center cell.

Comment: Tables are NEVER the best option for a layout. They are ALWAYS the best option for tabular data, of course. Not only is the markup horrible and harder to understand, but you will have several empty cells to accomodate for horizontal spacing. Plus tables are not as semantic as divs, making them a lot more tricky to style with CSS. 

HTML5 goes even further by adding tags such as <header> <footer> and <nav>

Comment: Not true...you can have div & CSS hell just as you can have table hell..especially when you have a complicated layout. 
And you don't need empty cells when you can add css margins and padding to table cells.  A good mix of table & css is often best..even stackoverflow mixes both very effectively even on my mobile devices.

Comment: Might not be the best solution, but it is consistent across browsers. Thanks Ed B!